# Backtickify code snippets on Stack Exchange

Tags: code-golf

Your goal is to input any arbitrary text, such as:

```
This is some text
```

And output that text formatted as code for posts (SE-flavored Markdown) and comments (mini-Markdown) on Stack Exchange, such as:

```
`This is some text`
`This is some text`
```

However, it gets trickier. Consider the input:

```
Perl has a variable called $`
```

The output must be

```
`` Perl has a variable called $` ``
`Perl has a varaible called $\``
```

The full rules for the formatting are:

- Full posts (full SE Markdown)

  - Step 1: count the least number for which there are not exactly that many consecutive backticks in the string. Let's call this `n`. (For example, for the string `potato`, `n` is 1, for `` this is a backtick: ` ``, `n` is 2, and for ``````` ` `` ``` ````` `````` ```````, `n` is 4.)
  - Step 2: wrap the string in `n` backticks. If the string starts or ends with a backtick, you must wrap with spaces as well. (For example, `potato` becomes `` `potato` ``, `` this is a backtick: ` `` becomes ``` `` this is a backtick: ` `` ```, and ``````` ` `` ``` ````` `````` ``````` becomes ``````` ```` ` `` ``` ````` `````` ```` ```````.
- Comments (mini-Markdown)

  - Wrap in `` ` `` and escape all `` ` ``'s with `` \` ``. (For example, `potato` becomes `` `potato` ``, `` this is a backtick: ` `` becomes `` this is a backtick: \` ``, and ``````` ` `` ``` ````` `````` ``````` becomes `` \` \`\` \`\`\` \`\`\`\`\` \`\`\`\`\`\` ``.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); the shortest answer in byte count wins.

Comment: What about space? ` ` does not get code-formatting...

Comment: @Quincunx Hmm... how are you supposed to format spaces in code anyway?

Comment: I have no idea. This post is where I learned how to format backticks and such.

Comment: The comment form also doesn't work for ``\``; to format a ``\``, you need to do `\`\`\\`\``. Also, anything ending with a ``\`` runs into the same problem: ``asdf\`` produces `asdf\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### APL (90)

(Yes, the APL charset does fit in a byte, here's IBM's [codepage 907](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_globalization_pdf_cp00907z.pdf).)

```
{⎕ML←3⋄(,/m,m,⍨{⍵=m:'\`'⋄⍵}¨⍵),⊂(⌽g),⍵,g←(''↑⍨∨/t[1,⍴t]),m/⍨0⍳⍨z∊⍨⍳⌈/0,z←,⊃⍴¨⍵⊂⍨t←⍵=m←'`'}
```

This is a function that takes a string, and returns an array of two strings, where the first string is the *comment* representation and the second string is the *full post* representation.

Tests:

```````
      backtickify←{⎕ML←3⋄(,/m,m,⍨{⍵=m:'\`'⋄⍵}¨⍵),⊂(⌽g),⍵,g←(''↑⍨∨/t[1,⍴t]),m/⍨0⍳⍨z∊⍨⍳⌈/0,z←,⊃⍴¨⍵⊂⍨t←⍵=m←'`'}
      ↑backtickify 'potato'
`potato`
`potato`

      ↑backtickify 'this is a backtick: `'
`this is a backtick: \``   
`` this is a backtick: ` ``

      ↑backtickify '` `` ``` ````` ``````'
`\` \`\` \`\`\` \`\`\`\`\` \`\`\`\`\`\``
```` ` `` ``` ````` `````` ````  

      ⍝ testcase for not wrapping with spaces
      ↑backtickify 'no`spaces``at````the`edges'
`no\`spaces\`\`at\`\`\`\`the\`edges`
```no`spaces``at````the`edges```
```````

Note: I gave the function a name for readability's sake, this is not strictly necessary to use it (you can just put the argument next to the anonymous function) so I didn't count it.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 119

```
s=gets.chop
c=1
c+=1while s=~/([^`]|\A)#{?`*c}([^`]|\z)/
puts ?`+s.gsub('`','\\\\`')+'`
'+?`*c+(s=~/$`|`^/?" #{s} ":s)+?`*c
```

Ungolfed:

```
def backtickify str, comment = false
  return "`#{str.gsub '`', '\\\\`'}`" if comment
  c = 1
  c += 1 while str =~ /([^`]|\A)#{?` * c}([^`]|\z)/
  str = ' ' + str + ' ' if str[0] == ?` || str[-1] == ?`
  return ?` * c + str + ?` * c
end
```