# Alternating factorial

Tags: code-golf, math

The alternating factorial is an alternating sum of decreasing factorials. For example, we could calculate the alternating factorial of 4 as follows:

- First, calculate the factorials from 4 down to 1:

$$
4!\quad3!\quad2!\quad1!\quad = \\
4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\qquad3\cdot2\cdot1\qquad2\cdot1\qquad1\quad= \\
24\quad6\quad2\quad1
$$

- Next, insert alternating signs between the products, always starting with \$\;-\$.

$$
24-6+2-1 = \\
19
$$

So 19 is the alternating factorial of 4. Mathematically, the alternating factorial is defined as
$$
\large\operatorname{af}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{n-i}i!
$$

For example,
$$
\operatorname{af}(4)=(-1)^3\times1!+(-1)^2\times2!+(-1)^1\times3!+(-1)^0\times4!=19
$$
The alternating factorial can also be calculated by the recurrence relation
$$
\operatorname{af}(n) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $\;n=0$} \\
n!-\operatorname{af}(n-1), & \text{if $\;n>0$}
\end{cases}
$$
The sequence of alternating factorials is [OEIS A005165](https://oeis.org/A005165).

### Task

Given a non-negative integer as input, output its alternating factorial. You don't need to worry about values exceeding your language's integer limit. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes (in each language) wins.

### Test cases

```
n   af(n)
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   5
4   19
5   101
6   619
7   4421
8   35899
9   326981
```

Comment: Please add a plain English explanation and a worked example.

Comment: @Shaggy I took a stab at it.

Comment: Can you check if the recurrence relation stated is correct? Because I’m not sure it is.

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian It's correct, just note how the last summand, when \$i=n\$ is \$(-1)^{(n-n)}n! = (-1)^{0}n!=n!\$ and by removing it we're left with \$-\operatorname{af}(n-1)\$ (since the remaining signs are in the _other_ alternating order to that of \$\operatorname{af}(n-1)\$).

Comment: @Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian the alternating is counted from the n downwards, not from 0 upwards, so, e.g., the role of 1! to the result will alternate with odd and even n too.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
R!ḅ-
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer, \$n\$, and yields its alternating factorial.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//UiHhuIUt/8W7wrUsw4dq4oCcID0@IOKAnSlZ//85)**

#### How?

```
R!ḅ- - Link: n
R    - range (n) -> [1, ..., n-1, n]
 !   - factorial -> [1!, ..., (n-1)!, n!]
   - - -1
  ḅ  - convert from base -1 -> n! - (n-1)! + ... [+/-] 1!
```

Comment: ...right, of course, base \$-1\$ does alternating sum, I always forget that :/

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
AlternatingFactorial
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8N8xpyS1KA/Iz0t3S0wuyS/KTMz5H1CUmVcSnRZtGRv7HwA)

Comment: I use Mathematica all the time and even I'm sometimes surprised by the builtins ... this sounds like a joke but it's not!

Answer (score 7):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 6 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
¯1⊥∘!⍳
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=O7Te8FHX0kcdMxQf9W4GAA&f=Szu04lHvZksA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Answer (score 6):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 28 bytes

```
f(k)=∑_{n=1}^k(-1)^{k-n}n!
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/biwt3b1goj)

Yea, I really could not think of any golfier way than to just copy the formula provided in the question. Not the most creative answer out there but at least it's the golfiest in Desmos (at least it better be....).

Answer (score 6):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <del>53</del> 42 bytes

```
i:?vl1=?n-30.
:?v\:1$:@*$1-
1.\6
00.\~~$1-
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTo/dmwxPT9uLTMwLlxuOj92XFw6MSQ6QCokMS1cbjEuXFw2XG4wMC5cXH5+JDEtIiwiaW5wdXQiOiI3Iiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

The bottom 3 lines calculate the factorial of a number and push it to the stack, the top line just subtracts the top 2 elements from the stack, and prints the top of the stack if there is just one.

After a number is printed, the `-` crashes and the program exits.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
Nest[++i!-#&,i=0,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCRaWztTUVdZTSfT1kBHOVbtf0BRZl5JtLKuXZoDkFsXnJyYVxeUmJeeGm2gYxn7HwA)

Comment: Ties with the built-in!

Comment: @TheThonnu Yes, in Mathematica there are many ways to code, between self-explained but long keywords to cool golfed versions

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n<2?n:n*f(n-2)+--n*f(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDoMwEAR7XnEFhQ/LKFAGTL6CBThKhPaQQTSW3@5Aqpli5utOt0/hsx0GMi85ews7oG9feKLyCqZlbcxfOXsJCmTp0RGop@am1kyxIJoEu6xLvcpbjU6VEYmvtIz3mUbuipR/)

This is based on the recurrence formula given on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A005165) for \$n > 1\$:

$$a(n) = n\times a(n-2) + (n-1)\times a(n-1)$$

This alternate form accepts either Numbers or Bigints as input:

```javascript
f=n=>n<2?n:n--*f(~-n)+n*f(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxDoMwEAXRnlNsQeHFMkKhCzi5ChbBCIT@IkBpLOfqhtC9YmZ2X7f327QeBvIZUvIW9oX28cYTxhRe/QxY4wI4edkUyFKFhkAt1Te0ZgoZUS/YZRnKRUbVOZUHRL7iPPzf2HGTxXQC)

Comment: Is there a reason to use `~-n` instead of `n-1`?

Comment: @Jacob Only for BigInt compatibility. It would be `n-1n` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n>1and~-n*f(n-1)+n*f(n-2)or n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3NdJscxJzk1ISFfKs8uwME_NS6nTztNI08nQNNbUhDCPN_CKFPKh67TQQRyEzT6EoMS89VcPQQNOqoCgzr0RDSTXFSkE1RUlVI08HqE1TUxOiBWYVAA)

Port of @Arnauld's JS answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>29</s> 31 bytes

*Edit: +2 bytes and complete change of approach to fix bug spotted by pajonk*

```r
\(x)Reduce(`-`,gamma(x:1+1),,T)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGKxJyStMTkEtulpSVpuhb7YzQqNINSU0qTUzUSdBN00hNzcxM1KqwMtQ01dXRCNCGqthQnFhTkVGoYWhka6EANgEotWAChAQ)

Comment: This doesn't match the test-case for `1`.

Comment: @pajonk - Drat!  Well spotted.  Hopefully fixed now (with complete re-think...)

Answer (score 4):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 48 bytes

```
f 0=1
f x|x>0=x*f(x-1)
g 0=0
g x|x>0=f(x)-g(x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NwcDWkCtNoaKmws7AtkIrTaNC11CTKx0obAAkIcJAQU3ddLDM/9zEzDwFW4XcxAKFdIVoAwU9PQXL2P8A)

My first answer in Curry.
I had to determine the factorial because I couldn’t find it in the standard library

Comment: [Here's it in 35 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/79C0dA2MalYoYKrQrGyptLO0FbDULdCq1JTUaNS11Dzf25iZp6CrUJuYoGChoGipkK0oYKenoJl7H8A) as a port of [my Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260369/56656).

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RR€puḋ
```

(Thunno 2 isn't on ATO yet)

It seems that I forgot to add a "factorial" built-in to Thunno 2...

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
RR€puḋ  # Implicit input                              5
R       # Push the range [1..input]                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 R      # For each number in this, push its range     [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
  €p    # Product of each inner list                  [1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
    uḋ  # Convert from base -1                        101
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>5.5</s> 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

*Edit: -0.5 bytes (1 nibble) thanks to xigoi*

```
/.\,$`*,$-
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWq_T1YnRUErR0VHQhAlDxBesNuAy5jLiMuUy4TLnMuMwhwgA)

Port of [my R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260148/95126).

```
/.\,$`/,$*-
 .          # map over
  \         # reverse of 
   ,$       # 1..input:
     `*     #   product of
       ,$   #   1..each element
            # (at this point we have list of
            # factorials in reverse order);
/           # now, fold over this from right to left
         -  # by subtraction
```

Comment: You can use `\`*,$` instead of `\`/,$*`. https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWq_T1YnRUErR0VHQhAlDxBesNuAy5jLiMuUy4TLnMuMwhwgA

Comment: @xigoi - Oh, yes, thanks.  Somehow I always forget that ``` `*``` exists (or maybe using Nibbles for a bit has made me think of folds for almost everything)...

Comment: @xigoi - How do you put `* into a codeblock in a comment, anyway?

Comment: Like this, I think (test): ``\`*`` EDIT: apparently not, lol.. I used to know, but forgot it.

Comment: Found it: If a backtick is somewhere in the middle, you can use double enclosing backticks: `\`\`like\`this\`\``, resulting in ``like`this``. If it's at the start or end, you can use singular enclosing backticks, and escape the backticks within the code: `\`\\`like\\`this\\`\``, resulting in `\`like\`this\``. So the comment `\`*,$` is accomplished with `\`\\`*,$\``.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Thanks a lot.  Also using this comment to test `\`*,$` Edit: it works!

Comment: There is even a challenge about it. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17650/backtickify-code-snippets-on-stack-exchange

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
:Yp-1ZQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yqyQNcwKvD/f1MA)

Comment: Cumulative product and evaluate polynomial, good idea!

Answer (score 4):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 4 bytes

```
n!-0
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z9PUdfg////lgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
   0 # Start with a(0)=0 (Oasis programs implicitly start with a(0)=1 unfortunately)
     # And calculate every following a(n) by:
  -  #  Subtracting
     #  the implicit previous term a(n-1)
n!   #  from n!
     # (and output the a(implicit input-argument)'th term implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 64 bytes

```
{(({})[()]<({([{}]()({}))([{}]({}))}{}{}([{}])((){}))>)}{}({}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/v1pDo7pWM1pDM9ZGo1ojuro2VkMTJKIJYYNYtdVACOZqamhogkTsQGJAORs7zf//LQA)

This does not compute any factorials as intermediate results.  Instead, it multiplies by successively smaller numbers and either adds or subtracts one.  Sample calculation for the alternating factorial of 5:

```
0  *6 +1 = 1
1  *5 -1 = 4
4  *4 +1 = 17
17 *3 -1 = 50
50 *2 +1 = 101
```

Comment: Wow, that's a clever and efficient way to calculate it!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
R!_@ƒ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9IMd7h2CSD/0d36xxuV3nUtMb9/39LAA)

### How it works

```
R!_@ƒ0 - Main link. Takes n on the left
R      - Range; [1, 2, ..., n]
 !     - Factorial; [1, 2, 6, ..., n!]
    ƒ0 - Reduce by the following, beginning with 0:
  _@   -   y - x
```

For a list `[a, b, c, d, e]`, `_@ƒ0` calculates

```
((((0 _@ a) _@ b) _@ c) _@ d) _@ e
= e _ (d _ (c _ (b _ (a _ 0))))
= e - d + c - b + a - 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ɾ¡uβ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwiyb7CoXXOsiIsIiIsIiEoXFxkKykgKyhcXGQrKVxuMCAgIDBcbjEgICAxXG4yICAgMVxuMyAgIDVcbjQgICAxOVxuNSAgIDEwMVxuNiAgIDYxOVxuNyAgIDQ0MjFcbjggICAzNTg5OVxuOSAgIDMyNjk4MSJd)

Port of the 4 byte jelly answer

### Explained

```
ɾ¡uβ 
ɾ    # range [1, n]
 ¡   # factorial of each
  uβ # converted from base -1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
řĐ1~⇹^⇹!·Å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6MwjEwzrHrXvjANixUPbD7f@/28GAA)

```
ř                 implicit input (n); řangify [1,2,...,n]
 Đ                Đuplicate 
  1~              -1
    ⇹             swap top two elements
     ^            -1^[1,2,3,...,n]
      ⇹           swap top two elements
       !          factorial [1!,2!,3!,...,n!]
        ·         dot product
         Å        Åbsolute value; implicit print
```

Uses that fact that \$\text{af}(n)=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i i!\right|\$

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 54 bytes

```
~(`.+
.+¶$$.($$'$&*
+`_(_(_+))
$$($.&$*$2$.1$*$1)
__
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcW7DYAgFAXQ/s5xxQckL4L/CRwDLCxsLIy1YzmAi6E5xTm3az/WUCpZcrklq4f69yFVyJrGweckP28tSKEaOkZq@AsWKSGV0iAgokWHHgNGTJg/) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.

```
~(`
```

Run the output of the rest of the program on the original input.

```
.+
.+¶$$.($$'$&*
```

Convert the input to unary and replace it with a command that replaces the input with an expression that converts the literal unary string back to decimal. The unary string represents `f(n)` at this point.

```
+`_(_(_+))
$$($.&$*$2$.1$*$1)
```

For `n>2`, repeatedly apply the recurrence relation `f(n)=n*f(n-2)+(n-1)*f(n-1)` to the unary string. `n` and `(n-1)` are represented in decimal while `f(n-2)` and `f(n-1)` remain represented in unary for the next pass.

```
__
_
```

`f(2)=1` while `f(n)=n` for `n<2` which is already correct.

Example: if `n=7`, then the rest of the program produces the following output:

```
.+
$.($'$(7*$(5*$(3*_2*_)4*$(4*_3*$(3*_2*_)))6*$(6*$(4*_3*$(3*_2*_))5*$(5*$(3*_2*_)4*$(4*_3*$(3*_2*_)))))
```

Retina will evaluate the expression using big integers so the limit is the length of the generated expression which has to fit in memory.

Note that there's an extra `$'` in the final expression in case it is empty to work around a Retina bug whereby `$.()` crashes Retina when it has no elements, but it's fine if it has a non-zero number of empty elements.

The recurrence relation is not used for `f(2)` because that would invoke `f(0)` whose representation would be empty, but `*` defaults to a RHS of `_` i.e. `1`. It could be done by representing `f(n)` with `$(n)` except that this triggers the empty length bug, so it needs another 3 bytes for a second copy of the workaround, making it overall a byte longer:

```
.+
.+¶$$.($$'$&*
~)+`_(_(_*))
$.&$*$$($$'$2)$.1$*$$($1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 38 bytes

Defined Name `a`:

```
=LAMBDA(n,IF(n,FACT(n)-a(n-1),))
```

After which, within the worksheet:

```
=a(A1)
```

for an input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>17 16</s> 12 bytes

```
$* *\,\,aFDv
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZrVLQUtGJ0YnQS3VzKIEJQmcXRFrFQJgA)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

*-4 thanks to @DLosc*

##### Explanation

```lisp
$* *\,\,aFDv   ; Input on command line
      \,a      ; Range from 1 to input
    \,         ; Range from 1 to each
$* *           ; Product of each inner list
         FDv   ; From a list of digits in base -1
               ; Implicit output
```

Old:

```lisp
({$*\,a}M\,a)FDv   ; Input on command line
         \,a       ; Range from 1 to input
 {     }M          ; Map over this list:
  $*               ;   Product of...
    \,a            ;   ...range from 1 to the number
(           )FD    ; Convert from a list of digits...
               v   ; ...in base -1
                   ; Implicit output
```

Comment: @DLosc thanks, updated

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õÊìJ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9crsSg&input=NQ)

```
õÊìJ     :Implicit input of integer U
õ        :Range [1,U]
 Ê       :Factorials
  ì      :Convert from base
   J     :-1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
0|-₁↰I&ḟ;I-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/36BG91FT46O2DZ5qD3fMt/bU/f/f8n8UAA)

#### Explanation

Uses the recurrence relation.

```
0             af(0) = 0
 |            Or
  -₁↰I        I = af(Input - 1)
      &ḟ;I-   Output = Input! - I
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
!n=n>0?prod(1:n)-!~-n:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//9fMc82z87AvqAoP0XD0CpPU1exTjfPyuC/g55CQVFmXklOnoaihoGVpabmfwA)

Uses the recursive formula.

Comment: -1 byte (and also works with Julia 1.0) `!n=n>0&&prod(1:n)-!~-n`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｉ↨ＥＮΠ…¹⁺²ι±¹
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjcDAooy80o0nBOLSzScEotTNXwTCzQ88wpKS_xKc5NSizQ0dRQCivJTSpNLNIIS89JTNQyBAjmlxRpGOgqZmkCgo-CXmp5YApQA8ayXFCclF0NNXx6tpFuWoxS70BzCBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｎ            First input as a number
  Ｅ             Map over implicit range
     …          Range from
      ¹         Literal integer `1` to
         ι      Current value
       ⁺        Plus
        ²       Literal integer `2`
    Π           Take the product
 ↨        ±¹    Interpret as base `-1`
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
Ti,n;o,T*:1n,n*_*;+s,_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=3VjJkts2EK3KIQflmB9AOAeTI4oR5W2iqXGVE2df7CSTVZlSYUhIwpgiGQCUR_6VXJxD8gn5GH9NusFdBDm2K6ewVCWS6H69N5r44-90rzZJ_OLlW-_wbZoIReRejopbKtYpFZKNRvpPkLPqlfdQrLMti9UTvWKHTAaCp4on8Zm15TFfJ9HKckZHJGf1aBguacFj31rxiN1yYbXvUvuUgTiphFNKP4CY7ADAxEoD1AKYLakSwZZKZMwyk25YlCLhE8FjRUq1yY4JiRD2KhEk2LDgKY_X5OH5Y5KlIVVMOlavVsF_p9XjTKWZIhGXiiQrEiQhSxNQVBIKP_QNqIWagHgJDIVC-g9Vkjas8RXGTHq7uZaVoqW2tZt6t4ET37BrruwpUCI-irWs0V-ZWk1O_jnnbnyauOfHcz924-Pl8elYust88eW7byOlVDR4ClyLCxAVg7qyesA7G7LJkyrksScYDW1nbP0WW44n0wik6vsROpkTHsNPLuYT_yLXFBSPWGxzhzwg03nlqCATmIdsRyNYq14DNaaMjcsOOdOZM295N9fOo2nK4tBGp9pbmtqJCF0N6jg1GoskG-LW9A2DNVr-VL1e8vAalqajUchWeWxsdPFcJzWZPNBcuRTBZBap3HP4rF0SXru5X1gMySUg7zS_M28azdFW69SakyOgC5fA2dJbsW1a45bXsw3UXyF1AR4n7wGIa8076Viy56RemqS2c0HG-n2LOAKqJlFrsVgonLeISoQDh4MJidowMcBbRFwwlYm4WMsdvIqoUpAv1BlwKXqTzjtJw3XG1OFoyybjswqdD-XIq6q6W8psWymqxL6GKajz9aI8A5aqDkWVvxrMpZC8Gltk4AKwQxO4BBvOrBBUe6Bpp8EHEAdAJlGStGMMuUb4wp-3c0npDNF9oDf03QwsxQK3g9nXFMxosOlmohYjaLxmtg-FAV0MXo19NLxJh1bGSwoywVKg6OY0uoi7OZHTXW0FsWHWgZx8pSDLmRoULKpqc65rM8zSfnb9gHVoRpAaQT6jBgjkcsvb2UUZCbx3awoj7LGG3WYReb_Mb2OIau2aGaI7KLQxI2vHwrJ-mv48cKjWrClwZhCoA49SdyyAbZQ_Zx251CWX7YR0e7NTB7ybnHhV1XLZzSDNVtU5ZCInx4Q6Xex2knQMznseIlR2UUC6HMZBgQ2DgKHHq41Yj3WsYVSBWEO_eJM4H7J19Mrb2v8xwrBd0TcJ7jBLM4ZjYu40jRDGOoQ4ecCgicpjmyQc9lGI6ay_ucRmOK7hBPs9YzBexuxaETvYBxEPnHzYaSHCzixImskNmfh67EAKwiWBXVztvcN80oNbPg6hsOkNnpj4zis4bx0llzQi9XR1U5kg3aImv-iGsDGpwSbvd9dXTRJM1dowc9Iczn4Gz59pz5fpjV8WEAQK8_B-qCz7a2UOTQNWLuuKkR3VKoa8mp_zlKhniX6SRCVr1pm78HrtQmPl9G9wpDaGmowoOwxo5RmdqivVJVdYrEBko149_i_UqGbNK_CRIfBV763d2C95oEcciMv3ArCQHvY-vA5Hhhv3gzKyr7cfnJ3dsCGAOdbUn92-c_fe_ZMPdDbq0gaVUkghvmMk5Guu-nuKtrP1vVQBP_zwo0cff_LpZxrWn0JY_fv9QEAwbvB4K64nZyPy5198-dXX3zx-8u13359r9Ik_A_iJ3w-PFOMDzl4ZWJs_aOCpd7cfExaNrD9q1tnde_2ssGhk_alw1nTIUVMj688F6-zOEO_sjpH5l5x5djLAOzsxsv5aqjysM54r4Lxdf_56gqURDZhtJZYL0_GRdGO5dE-twwKsCZdIOD0djwdojpDG9U-BxmmcegT6ozI_R8nPSyRZiWRrOFTJv9YMH4zaplf_aKzWF9N2y34An2KPup0RJOJ3XDEhQ-F3O9F1_wCjeyLv2YsKTa56NG2J6ByMBBvhXjmGoRYv8w7dAQMMkG7YKEoCPAHyrsD_WmREt5chJcncKl4msOFcH-pgll1DNgDRBnDo4MmOaCpbtoXyWEuMRsWJWUtRSCVXkwB0fhz24s_b-c2_)

### Explanation

```
T            Push -1 (b)
i,n;         [1..n] range of input
o            Reverse it
,            Map in [n..1]:
  T*:          Multiply (b) by -1 (since -1^0 = 1
  1            Push 1
  n            Push curr. item
  ,n*_         Reduce 1..n by product
  *            mul. w/ b
;            End map
+            sum (works for 0 case since sum of [] is 0)
s,_          drop b

implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <del>40</del> 35 bytes

saved 5 bytes thanks to the comment.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P00jT9M2MalYo7g0VyPX1lAnT6egKD9FIxvIzNXRzdbU1PxfUJSZV6KRpmEJZAMA)

```
f(n)=abs(sum(m=1,n,prod(k=1,m,-k)))
```

Comment: A port of @KiptheMalamute's Pyt answer is only 35 bytes: `f(n)=abs(sum(m=1,n,prod(k=1,m,-k)))`.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 10 bytes

```
_1#.1!@+i.
```

Port of [Jonathan Allan's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) smart Jelly answer.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxKt5QWc9Q0UE7Uw8isFGTKzU5I19JWyFNzU4hU8_QACK-YAGEBgA)

```
_1#.1!@+i.
        i.  NB. range [0,n)
    1  +    NB. vectorized increment
     !@     NB. factorial of each
_1#.        NB. convert from base -1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 32 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n<2?n:n*f(n-2)+f(--n)*n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDbboMwDH3vV1hIlcJNo1CqMsr2MO0rBg8oJB3aZiqSaWiIXx8zGdA1io@OT2zLJ9w/cz6OkqHdY4an8BHv0aHUD21XMt9H28F0GGvU8FHWyGzoN0BnEkR3EVyL6qWADPrAg525MWFCERA/TGy/D4lG8TGhJAoPyXE3pGYKb1Bp4K9l6xAK/ibav2FW3j2HeZc8UcSWB//zyJq7ZdMCmxapsRIdtQXpTE@g6m/RSLasaN/NgrMqKbiuqV4sLbY0TTIP6Y2sSJZM27eqIHX9B9NVXAsuLZVIZm0r8B@AcKtyJDfaA@WthlWWiWIeOxhshf5skexshvGHy/fyrEb/6xc)

*Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260122/9481)*

Answer (score 2):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 39 bytes

```
Minus foldl 0 Product map IFrom1 IFrom1
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack)!

#### Worked example

```
                4
IFrom1          [1,2,3,4]
IFrom1          [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
Product map     [1,2,6,24]
Minus foldl 0   19
```

where the last bit is

```
Minus          Subtract first argument from second
      foldl    Left-fold on that function
            0  starting with an accumulator value of 0
```

and so our result is -(-(-(-0+1)+2)+6)+24 = 19.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```Raku
{[[&(&[R-])]] [\*] 1..$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjpaTUMtOkg3VjM2ViE6RitWwVBPTyW@9j9XcWKlgh5QUVp@kUKcocF/AA)

There has got to be a better way of doing that second reduce. For reference, the `[op]` means reduce, the `\` means keep the intermediate values, and the `R` metaoperator reverses the order of the subtraction. So `[\*]` the range 1 to input will return a list of factorials from 1 to input. From this we want to fold right over the list with reversed subtraction, which would be `[R-]` right? However `R-` also has reversed precedence, so `a R- b R- c` is equivalent to `c - b - a` rather than `c - (b - a)`. So we have to make it a function rather than an operator with `&[R-]`, but inserting it into the reduction operator requires an extra pair of `[]`s as well as an `&()` for some reason (but `*R-*` also doesn't work for reasons). This bloats it up to the point where `reduce &[R-]` is now the same length, blergh.

Alternatively, we can construct a sequence and index into it:

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 30 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Steffan*

```perl6
{(0,{abs $_-=$*=++$}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNApzoxqVhBJV7XVkXLVltbpVZPT09LM1olPrb2P1dxYqWCHlBlWn6RQpyhwX8A)

If [this IO method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25537/76162) ends up allowed as default, then this can be shortened to [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4JCmYPvfQKc6MalYQSVeV0NFy1ZbW0WzVk9PT@u/NVdxIkhJtEp8rEJafpFCnKHBfwA).

Comment: `{(0,{abs $_-=$*=++$}...*)[$_]}`

Comment: @naffetS Nice spot! Doesn't work for the pure sequence version though sadly

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 31 bytes

```haskell
x!1=abs x
x!y=(1-x*y)!(y-1)
```

```
(0!)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWuysUDW0Tk4oVKrgqFCttNQx1K7QqNRU1KnUNNSEqbirkJmbmKdgqFBRl5pUoqAC5BQoaBoqaCtGGCnp6CpaxEHUwEwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L!®β
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260123/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR/HQunOb/v83BQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W95bJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2fv99FA@tO7fpv85/AA).

**Outputting the infinite sequence would be 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):**

```
0λN!α
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NxuP8VzG///BwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
L     # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 !    # Get the factorial of each
  ®β  # Convert it from a base-(-1) list to a base-10 integer
      # (which is output implicitly as result)

 λ    # Start a recursive environment,
      # to output the infinite sequence
      # (which is output implicitly at the end)
0     # Start with a(0)=0
      # Where every other a(n) is calculated by:
      #  (implicitly push the previous term a(n-1)
    α #  Get the absolute difference between it
  N!  #  and n!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 15 bytes

```
?@(!1→ρΓ³#R(ⁿ*Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vaG0y//8/QCghMeKGks@BzpPCsyNSKOKBvyrOo///Ng)

Ohm is very weird. It thinks that the factorial of `1` is `nil`, doesn't do base conversion from -1 like other answers and doesn't like formatting numbers correctly sometimes.

### Explained

```
?@(!1→ρΓ³#R(ⁿ*Σ
?     # only execute this program if the input is not 0
@(    # the range 2..input
!     # factorial of each
1→ρ  # append 1 to that and rotate right. This is because `1!` gives nil
Γ     # Push -1
³#R(  # range(0, n - 1)[::-1]
ⁿ     # -1 to the power of each of those numbers 
Σ     # summed.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 54 bytes

```rust
fn a(n:i64)->i64{if n<2{n}else{n*a(n-2)+(n-1)*a(n-1)}}
```

All my attempts at golfing this straightforward recursive solution just made the code longer, so I welcome any help!

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBLasMwEKVL-xSTrKRWBkuxHbspPUFvYEwwQQZBOklkmS6ETtKNF-2qJ2pPU8UJrZVZzPA-MzDv_UMPvRm_OoTXViGhYD8H0yXld-GpluCjKjKaPPtuVQf4JCw6ue-lxXuvJoI--M7pBDh17rL9c_cSHbVCs8cFWU6H6JJu4qg7aKgVHgfDYHfQWu7MtsX-TeoGFEIdw7XqlEHasH_MGfA5Fjd4xSCf48zr1ZzIPZEGKwWDIvSsGWSZCEwlg1VeVoGt8pwoqpI3E9fYP6nte6nNVp4WpCXTn_T2UbqBOJqlYyebAxva3Dmv80kXX0Mdx8v8BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
aF.!S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9FNTzH4/39TAA)

#### Explanation

```
aF.!SQ    # implicitly add Q
          # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
    SQ    # inclusive range from 1 to Q
  .!      # map to factorial
aF        # fold over the absolute difference
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 49 bytes

```sh
r=i=$[$1>0]
for n ({$1..2})((r=r*n+(i=-i)))
<<<$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcohDoAwDABAzysqKloIzYZe@QhBzCzUjKQ4yN4@CKfvvo6eCzF1V1PcMK5hH8rpUIEejCJLYyJXH@tEprMx85BSQu/8P/teEImhMeQCaP0F)

This turned into a super interesting problem, because managing the right base cases for a recursive solution takes too many bytes. Instead, I came up with an equivalent form:

$$ \mbox{af}(n)=\mbox{af}'(1,-1,n)=\begin{cases}
r,i,0 :& 0
\\ r,i,1 :& r
\\ r,i,n :& \mbox{af}'(r\cdot n+i,-i,n-1)
\end{cases} $$

There's probably a way to make both this form and the program shorter. I had to use `r=i=$[$1>0]` instead of `r=i=1` to get the \$ n=0 \$ case, otherwise this program will output `-1`. Also, you may notice that since my program uses a range between `$1` and `2`, that it doesn't follow the recursion above for \$n = 1\$. It turns out, looping upwards to 2 results in \$(1\cdot 1 -1)\cdot 2 + 1 = 1\$, so it all works out okay.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 29 bytes

Uses standard System V ABI with signature `long afact(int n)`. The input `n` is taken in `rdi`, and the output is given in `rax`.

```
31 c0 85 ff 74 16 ff c0 57 59 48 f7 e1 e2 fb 50 ff cf e8 e9 ff ff ff 48 29 04 24 58 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRZj9MwEH73r5gtWqlhmx6w2oceK4F44QHxgAQP29XKdZzUi@MJPnqA@O1l7KSlCxJIG1XpeDzH982RFXfrgxRrhN7hbqW8g5vre8ZmYLirgZd6GP9zjBJCXkpd3lwz5qTwCg0Mvdx5BvRUGldckwcXPvovnvOQn0ZslKlGVopgndpIEFivlOEp30aSDs2z46cEpmph9pXxYDLSlag1bh3sbq7h0959hjdv38cagDJgC0UiBt8En858x5L7NPGegVNGSPBr5YB@Log1cCi581BZ3BIXKINpy9WXzknjFdd7MBfZANCQ5GqudRdsw3WQDrCk5NxKqDAG8AhbtF@Bm/2W7wfg6EyF4WTjXKhjdu5hDPMFuc1hMh4PWRdQaMltAh3PO7Qg@W4QX0cLK32wRJVSLsZJ5yWBl4UaxFfSPH6Hh4fE@oHMzdE1KtASHSiVdf5YEOlj/Ih6klRUoJQwyp1NLC3dW9Fqm@DWqdLpgE26OJl6VUs3ZUcEpW6OtSde8JJI9/M8S6o66FPQOEpw5vQk/0VsVtfODjanYVP@DM9TyBXRaufG5JPs3LeQ4lQpQb08bkEXN6y8pXMCW1qs4Rs1s4A765p76NMcJEMyO78Y/Jk@VoWbomvX70LFRp73pi0NSYce3HYLzFi74uwFtUKHQsLc@ULhcH3L2GgElRCEuR4K6Pac9p22/kvkkn98Te47L2lG/tqdGWNRqLky/Q2qIoMfKX1Jc5ZM1GI8AzV/NaH31VXLNEG3dFv2l7022mWRTeFSF0uz7A2ABq9LksUMHZ84pOMZ@8kSLwLL2D8/Uv8lNRyRguHqsQh1A/k7yD8QKKlb@8Mv)

### Explanation

The function implements the recurrence relation \$\operatorname{af}(n)\$ as given in the question.

```
afact:
    ; clear rax
    xor eax, eax

    ; return if n=0
    test edi, edi
    jz __afact_retn

    ; factorial first
    ; set eax to 1
    inc eax
    
    ; n into rcx
    push rdi
    pop rcx

    ; n times:
__afact_flp:
    ; rax *= n(--)
    mul rcx
    loop __afact_flp
    
    ; n! is in rax
    ; save it
    push rax
    
    ; get afact(n-1) in rax
    dec edi
    call afact

    ; subtract rax from qword [rsp] (n!)
    sub qword [rsp], rax
    
    ; pop and return
    pop rax

__afact_retn:
    ret
```